# What to do when a question is not a duplicate, but a duplicate of a template?

Tags: discussion

Maybe my question is duplicated throughout meta, but I don't know how to exactly phrase this, so sorry if we have dealt with it before.

I have seen many questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108862/how-to-install-pyodbc-64-bit).  The general question is how to install 64 bit *enter your favorite python module*?  The answer is always [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).  How do you deal with questions which have been answered before multiple times, but are not exactly duplicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You close them as duplicates.**

Trivial differences shouldn't prevent questions with the same underlying problem and the same answer being closed as duplicates.  This makes life easier for answerers because a single great answer serves many questions.  This improves life for askers because they get the definitive, highly polished answer instead of an off-the-cuff response.

Obviously if a question about a particular module *cannot* be fully answered by the definitive response, the question should *not* be closed as a duplicate.  Answers should discuss the differences for that module and make reference to the general answer as appropriate.